# Django: Formset saved data retrieved single raw

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am using Inlineformsets for an app. Data gets saved but when I retrieve data, main form data is correctly retrieved however in case of childmodel, only first raw is retrieved from DB.

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def invoice_detail(request,pk):  


    invoice_detailmain = serviceinvoice.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if invoice_detailmain.user != request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied
    invoiceitems =invoice_detailmain.serviceitems1.filter(pk=pk,user=request.user)

    return render(request,'account/invoicedetail.html',{'invoice_detailmain':invoice_detailmain,
                                                        'invoiceitems':invoiceitems})
```

**template.html**

```
{% for items in invoiceitems %}
<tr><td>{{ items.Product }}</td>
<td>{{ items.UOM }}</td>
<td>{{ items.Quantity }}</td>
<td>{{ items.Rate }}</td>
<td>{{ items.Tax_rate }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class serviceinvoice(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='invoice')    
    invoice_number=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    #invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default = increment_invoice_number, null = True, blank = True)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
    invoice_receivable=models.ForeignKey(Receivables,null=True)
    total_amount=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    total_amountwithtax=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    company_det=models.ForeignKey(Company,related_name='companydetails')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "invoice_number"),)
        ordering=('-invoice_number',) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_number

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('invoice:editinvoice', args=[self.invoice_number])

class serviceinvoiceitems(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='serviceinvoiceitems')
    invoice_number=models.ForeignKey(serviceinvoice,related_name='serviceitems1')
    Product=models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
    UOM=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Quantity=models.FloatField(null=True)
    Rate=models.FloatField(null=True)
    Tax_rate=models.FloatField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_number
```

Comment: Show the code for your models, how are `serviceinvoice` and `serviceinvoice.serviceitems1` connected?

Comment: @SindriGuðmundsson updated question.

Comment: have you tried removing the `pk=pk` parameter from your filter? That's filtering `serviceinvoiceitems` by the primary key of the `serviceinvoice`'s that owns the item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your filtering is incorrect. Instead of

```
invoiceitems = invoice_detailmain.serviceitems1.filter(pk=pk,user=request.user)
```

you should be using

```
invoiceitems = invoice_detailmain.serviceitems1.filter(user=request.user)
```

Although I'm baffled to why you have a primary key from both `serviceinvoice` and `serviceinvoiceitems` to your user model. It would probably be enough for you to specify

```
invoiceitems = invoice_detailmain.serviceitems1.all()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Learning Django, was not familiar with serviceitems1 uses. Thank a lot, its working.